# Problem with testing slider element with TestCafe

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I don't know how to correctly write a test for slider element in this case:

```
    <Slider
                  defaultValue={pickupValue.length ? pickupValue : [15, 15]}
                  aria-labelledby="range-slider"
                  valueLabelDisplay="auto"
                  onChange={(e, value) => handleChangePickupTime(value)}
                  valueLabelFormat={(value) => formatSliderToDisplay(value)}
                  step={0.5}
                  marks
                  min={0}
                  max={24}
                />
```

there what I tried:

```
constructor{
this.productPickupCutoff= Selector('[ pickupValue : [10,12]}]');
}
  async setOnProductPickupCutoff(){
    await t
    .click(this.productPickupCutoff);
    .drag(this.productPickupCutoff);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to use the `aria-labelledby` attribute in the Selector for consistency. Also, you need to specify offset parameters for the [drag](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402705/reference/test-api/testcontroller/drag) action:

```
const slider = Selector('[aria-labelledby="range-slider"]'); 

test(`New Test`, async t => {    
    await t
        .drag(slider, 70, 0);
});
```